# What does SQlite select/fetchone statement returns in Python as a rule?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, nonetype

I'm working with a sqlite database and part of it is doing querys and writing data. To do so, I generally check if that row matching a specific id has a field, or some field already filled. The problem is I'm not getting consistent results when it comes to None returns. I do this

```
cur=conn.cursor()
cur.execute('''SELECT FT1,FT2 FROM Results WHERE id=?''',(idm,))
foo=cur.fetchone()
```

In this case, what I get is `None`. But here

```
cur=conn.cursor()
cur.execute('''SELECT YFT1,YFT2 FROM Results WHERE id=?''',(idm,))
foo=cur.fetchone()
```

What I get is `(None,None)`

Is there any rule this is following that I'm not aware of? For my code to work, in order to check if there is a None return I have to do:

```
if foo is None:
```

or in the other case

```
if foo[0] is None:  /  if None in foo:
```

What I want to know is what am I missing in order to get a sentence that works for both cases.

Thanks

Comment: take a look at your database.  it seems likely that the (None,None) comes from a row where YFT1 and YFT2 are null, as compared to the first Select where there are no matches.

Answer (score 0):

As @jdigital commented, I tested what he said and here is the issue

If what I'm querying a row by an id that doesn't exist using fetchone, I get `None`

If I'm querying a row that does exist, but the fields wanted are null, I get `(None,None)`

If I'm querying multiple rows that exist, but those fields are empty, I get `[(None,None),(None,None)]`

If I'm querying multiple rows that doesn't exist, I get `[]`

Comment: More accurately, `fetchall()` always returns a list. And you get a tuple of fields for every available row